# SPROC that returns unique calculated INT for each call

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm implementing in my application an event logging system to save some event types from my code, so I've created a table to store the log type and an Incremental ID:

```
|LogType|CurrentId|
|info   |    1    |
|error  |    5    |
```

And also a table to save the concrete log record

```
|LogType|IdLog|Message        |
|info   |1    |Process started|
|error  |5    |some error     |
```

So, every time I need to save a new record I call a SPROC to calculate the new id for the log type, basically: `newId = (currentId + 1)`. But I am facing an issue with that calculation because if multiple processes calls the SPROC at the same time the "generated Id" is the same, so I'm getting log records with the same Id, and every record must be Id-unique.

This is my SPROC written for **SQL Server 2005**:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetLogId]
    @LogType VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE @IdCreated VARCHAR(MAX)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TBL_ApplicationLogId WHERE LogType = @LogType)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @CurrentId BIGINT
        SET @CurrentId = (SELECT CurrentId FROM TBL_ApplicationLogId WHERE LogType = @LogType)

        DECLARE @NewId BIGINT
        SET @NewId = (@CurrentId + 1)

        UPDATE TBL_ApplicationLogId
        SET CurrentId = @NewId
        WHERE LogType = @LogType

        SET @IdCreated = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @NewId)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TBL_ApplicationLogId VALUES(@LogType, 0)

        EXEC @IdCreated = usp_GetLogId @LogType
    END

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16, 1)

    END CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

    SELECT @IdCreated
END
```

I would appreciate your help to fix the sproc to return an unique id on every call.

It has to work on **SQL Server 2005**. Thanks

Comment: You can try generating CurrentId using INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you achieve what you want with an identity column?
Then you can just let SQL Server guarantee uniqueness.

Example:

```
create table my_test_table
(
  ID int identity
 ,SOMEVALUE nvarchar(100)
);

insert into my_test_table(somevalue)values('value1');
insert into my_test_table(somevalue)values('value2');

select * from my_test_table
```

If you **must** issue the new ID values yourself for some reason, try using a sequence, as shown here:

```
if object_id('my_test_table') is not null
begin
  drop table my_test_table;
end;
go

create table my_test_table
(
  ID int
 ,SOMEVALUE nvarchar(100)
);
go

if object_id('my_test_sequence') is not null
begin
  drop sequence my_test_sequence;
end;
go

CREATE SEQUENCE my_test_sequence
  AS INT  --other options are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE 0
  NO MAXVALUE;
go

insert into my_test_table(id,somevalue)values(next value for my_test_sequence,'value1');
insert into my_test_table(id,somevalue)values(next value for my_test_sequence,'value2');
insert into my_test_table(id,somevalue)values(next value for my_test_sequence,'value3');

select * from my_test_table
```

One more edit: I think this is an improvement to the existing stored procedure, given the requirements.  Include the new value calculation directly in the UPDATE, ultimately return the value directly from the table (not from a variable which could be out of date) and avoid recursion.

A full test script is below.

```
if object_id('STACKOVERFLOW_usp_getlogid') is not null
begin
  drop procedure STACKOVERFLOW_usp_getlogid;
end
go

if object_id('STACKOVERFLOW_TBL_ApplicationLogId') is not null
begin
  drop table STACKOVERFLOW_TBL_ApplicationLogId;
end
go

create table STACKOVERFLOW_TBL_ApplicationLogId(CurrentID int, LogType nvarchar(max));
go

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[STACKOVERFLOW_USP_GETLOGID](@LogType VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @IdCreated VARCHAR(MAX)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM STACKOVERFLOW_TBL_ApplicationLogId WHERE LogType = @LogType)
    BEGIN
      UPDATE STACKOVERFLOW_TBL_APPLICATIONLOGID
      SET CurrentId = CurrentID + 1
      WHERE LogType = @LogType
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      --first time: insert 0.
      INSERT INTO STACKOVERFLOW_TBL_ApplicationLogId(CurrentID,LogType) VALUES(0,@LogType);
    END
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    begin
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    end
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 1);
  END CATCH
  select CurrentID from STACKOVERFLOW_TBL_APPLICATIONLOGID where LogType = @LogType;

  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  begin
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END
end
go

exec STACKOVERFLOW_USP_GETLOGID 'TestLogType1';
exec STACKOVERFLOW_USP_GETLOGID 'TestLogType1';
exec STACKOVERFLOW_USP_GETLOGID 'TestLogType1';
exec STACKOVERFLOW_USP_GETLOGID 'TestLogType2';
exec STACKOVERFLOW_USP_GETLOGID 'TestLogType2';
exec STACKOVERFLOW_USP_GETLOGID 'TestLogType2';
```

Comment: No, Joseph. I can not modify this table structure. It must work this way.

Comment: Ok, see my edited version of the answer - you can call a sequence from inside your stored procedure.  Does that help?

Comment: The SEQUENCE statement was  introduced in SQL Server 2012, question is about SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @JorgeRamírez - Then you are going to incur technical debt and have to live with much more complex, fragile, prone to error code.  Guarantees of uniqueness in a concurrent environment are messy, and doing so without threads blocking each other is even messier.  Identity columns deal with all of it.  Even if you create a single new table solely for this purpose (rather than adding an identity column to yourTBL_ApplicationLogId table, which would seem to be the best option), this is by far and away a better design than re-inventing this wheel yourself.

Comment: @MatBailie Maybe, but it's my current scenario and I have to deal with it.

Comment: By returning the CurrentID outside of the transaction *(after the `COMMIT TRANSACTION`)* you enter in to a race condition.  Between the `COMMIT` and the `SELECT` a currently blocked concurrent process could begin working on that table, resulting in both executions returning the same value.  This is not concurrency safe.

Comment: @MatBailie: great observation, I edited the post with that in mind.

Comment: @JosephStyons I have tested your latest changes and it seems to be working fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not much you can do here, but validate that:

- table TBL_ApplicationLogId is indexed by column LogType.
- @LogType sp parameter is the same data type as column LogType in table TBL_ApplicationLogId, so it can actually use the index if/when it exists.
- If you have a concurrency issue, maybe forcing the lock level on table TBL_ApplicationLogId during select and update can help. Just add (ROWLOCK) after the table name, Eg: TBL_ApplicationLogId (ROWLOCK)

Answer (score 0):

You want your increment and read to be atomic, with a guarantee that no other process can increment in between.

You also need to ensure that the log type exists, and again for it to be thread-safe.

Here's how I would go about that, but you would be advised to read up on how it all works in SQL Server 2005 as I have not had to deal with these things in nearly 8 years.

This should complete the two actions atomically, and also without transactions, in order to prevent threads blocking each other.   *(Not just performance, but also to avoid **DEADLOCK**s when interacting with other code.)*

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetLogId]
    @LogType VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN


    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    -- Hold our newly created id in a temp table, so we can use OUTPUT

    DECLARE @new_id TABLE (id BIGINT);


    -- I think this is thread safe, doing all things in a single statement
    ----> Check that the log-type has no records
    ----> If so, then insert an initialising row
    ----> Output the newly created id into our temp table

    INSERT INTO
        TBL_ApplicationLogId (
            LogType,
            CurrentId
        )
    OUTPUT
        INSERTED.CurrentID
    INTO
        @new_id
    SELECT
        @LogType, 1
    FROM
        TBL_ApplicationLogId
    WHERE
        LogType = @LogType
    GROUP BY
        LogType
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) = 0
    ;


    -- I think this is thread safe, doing all things in a single statement
    ----> Ensure we don't already have a new id created
    ----> Increment the current id
    ----> Output it to our temp table

    UPDATE
        TBL_ApplicationLogId
    SET
        CurrentId = CurrentId + 1
    OUTPUT
        INSERTED.CurrentID
    INTO
        @new_id
    WHERE
        LogType = @LogType
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @new_id)
    ;


    -- Select the result from our temp table
    ----> It must be populated either from the INSERT or the UPDATE

    SELECT
        MAX(id)    -- MAX used to tell the system that it's returning a scalar
    FROM
        @new_id
    ;


END
```